# Login facebook with curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to login facebook with curl. I already tested in browser with condition disable cookie, javascript and Opera mini 4 User-agent. It login succefully. with that i check with inspect what happens within request header and response headers. i check it already. the first step facebook will generate 4 random values within hidden type input "**lsd, jazoest,m_ts,li**". the second step after post it will redirect to specific location with session. Cause, i disable cookie. so i see facebook switch to session. after this step. i should see my timeline page. but, it nothing happens. it just post to login page without follow location. object httpConnect is wrapper from curl.

```
$headers = [
        'User-agent: Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.0.10992/35.5561; U; hr) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10',
    ];

$facebook = new httpConnect('https://m.facebook.com/');

$facebook->setHeaders($headers);

$facebook->setOptions();

$facebook->sendRequest();

$sourceCode = $facebook->getResponse();

preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="(.*?)" autocomplete="off" \/>/', $sourceCode, $lsd);

preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="jazoest" value="(.*?)" autocomplete="off" \/>/', $sourceCode, $jazoest);

preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="m_ts" value="(.*?)" \/>/', $sourceCode, $m_ts);

preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="li" value="(.*?)" \/>/', $sourceCode, $li);

$data = [
    'lsd' => $lsd[1],
    'jazoest' => $jazoest[1],
    'm_ts'  => $m_ts[1],
    'li' => $li[1],
    'try_number' => 0,
    'unrecognized_tries' => 0,
    'email' => 'email',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'login' => 'Log In',
    '_fb_noscript' => 'true'
];

$options = [
    CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $data,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,
];

$facebook = new httpConnect('https://m.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&amp;lwv=100&amp;refid=8');

$facebook->setHeaders($headers);

$facebook->setOptions($options);

$facebook->sendRequest();

echo $facebook->getResponse();
```

Comment: Provide some output. What Is in the response? Btw how do you think the session gets handled without cookies?

Comment: @slepic I debug it within conditions. i disabled the browser cookies, javascript and last i change original user agent to opera mini. It login succefully.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing apples with pears? What browser are you talking about?

Comment: @slepic my environemtn is windows. with current browser chrome 64bit

Comment: OH Wait you mean u tried this with your browser with disabled stuff And it worked. One has to be a detective to understand you... Anyway the response?

Comment: @slepic what the response u want? request header, response header, or response?

Comment: @slepic first response header https://justpaste.it/2ojnx

Comment: @slepic response header return by curl different from browser with modified user agent condition. This is response header by browser https://justpaste.it/5g4hi

Comment: @slepic in curl, curl get response some additional header by facebook. `content-security-policy`

Comment: _“I need to login facebook with curl”_ - no, you don’t. That is explicitly not allowed, and Facebook will block your server IP once they discover what you are doing. If you need to do _anything_ on Facebook in an automated fashion, use their APIs. If the APIs don’t offer what you are looking for - then it is not allowed.

Comment: [do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: as an example of why your regex-parsing code is bugged: if lsd contains: `<input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="foo&amp;bar" autocomplete="off" />`, your regex code would read `foo&amp;bar`, which is invalid and won't get you logged in, but a HTML parser would correctly read: `foo&bar` (because &amp; must be decoded to &, but your regex parser isn't doing that - but there's many such cases, for example `&Aering;` must be decoded to `Å`, but your regex code is NOT doing that either. stop parsing HTML with regex, it's extremely unreliable. use a HTML parser.)

Comment: @hanshenrik I updated my code but i stuck how to correctly post data. it seem like the post data empty. complete code pastelink.net/thro

Answer (score 1):

your login code is not even close to being complete,

first off, the first request to m.facebook.com to get the original cookie requires the `accept-language` header (seriously, it won't let you login without accept-language, weird shit, here is the 1 i am using: `accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8`),

second, you're trying to parse HTML with regex, [stop doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003), you have to use a proper HTML parser instead, PHP [has several HTML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/1067003) (including DOMDocument, XMLReader, XMLParser, SimpleXml,...), third, you're trying to hardcode the login form parameters, don't do that, extract them dynamically, you must fetch all `<input>` elements that is a descendant of the `login_form` element dynamically, and add them to your login request, and just fill out "email" and "pass" inputs manually.

next up, sometimes you will randomly get a request to install the facebook mobile app instead after logging in (this doesn't happen every time, but seemingly randomly), when you get this question, you *MUST* answer either yes or no, facebook will not allow you to continue the login before you answer. the question can be detected by looking for an `<a>` element with a `href=` that contains the string `/login/save-device/cancel/`, and you can answer `not interested` by doing a simple GET request to the href pointed to by that a-element. finally, login success can be verified by looking for an a-element with an href containing `/logout.php`

you can find a sample login code from the FacebookRelay constructor of the msgme project, here: https://github.com/divinity76/msgme/blob/master/src/php/relays/facebook.relay.php

Comment: I updated my code but i stuck how to correctly post data. it seem like the post data empty. complete code https://pastelink.net/thro

Comment: @olivia don't hardcode the login fields, they change all the time, fetch them dynamically from the HTML. parse out all `<input>` fields under the `<form id="login_form">` and add them to your login POST. also your html parsing code is bugged, it incorrectly parses `&amp;` from `<input name="lsd"...>`  when present, fix that.

Comment: I succefully login inside facebook. my last problem is empty post value. i think i don;t need dynamically parse html. cause, my condition already fits. i request old school request. all Static. all switch to session. otherwise i request with enable javascript. I disabled it all,

Comment: @olivia it did work because you were lucky and no characters were html-encoded in lsd. run this code, what do you get? http://paste.debian.net/plain/1089444